# Socket.io with Express and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm trying to implement simple WebSocket connection by using Socket.io, Express and ReactJS.

Here is the server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3030;

const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`)); 
const io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);

  socket.on('test', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
}) 

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {   
    res.sendFile(
        path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'), 
        err => err && res.status(500)   
    ); 
});
```

And now React component code:

```
import React from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3030/test');

socket.emit('test', {
    message: 'oh hi'
})

export const App = () => (
    <p> Sample <p/>
);
```

The result is simple - I get `console.log` with `socket.id` (so the connection is working) but I don't get the second one with `data`. It looks like for some unknown reason the `emit` and `on` events are not working properly. I also tried fire `emit` with `onClick` function passed to button component, but still nothing.

Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT:**

Just to make it clear, `on('disconnect')` is also working:

```
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  });
```

Comment: const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3030'); working fine checked the backend log message : 'oh hi' was printing in backend.

Answer (score 0):

My working example looks a little different too yours

```
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){

  socket.once("disconnect", function(){});

  socket.on("create", function(payload){});

  socket.on("join", function(payload){});

  socket.on("newMessage", function(payload){});

  socket.on("login", function(payload){});

  socket.on("logout", function(payload){});

  connections.push(socket);

  socket.emit("groups", groups);

  io.sockets.emit("users", users);

 });
```

// CLIENT

```
var io = require("socket.io-client");

componentWillMount(){
  this.socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
  this.socket.on("connect", () => {});
  this.socket.on("disconnect", this.onConnect);
  this.socket.on("groups", this.onReceivedGroups);
  this.socket.on("group", this.onReceivedGroup);
  this.socket.on("users", this.onUsers);
  this.socket.on("info", this.onInfo);
  this.socket.on("launch", this.onLaunch);
  this.socket.on("close", this.onClose);
  this.socket.on("closed", this.onClosed);
}

onConnect = () => {};

onReceivedGroups = () => {};

onReceivedGroup = () => {};

onUsers = () => {};

onInfo = () => {};

onLaunch = () => {};

onClose = () => {};

onClosed = () => {};

render = () => {};
```

This is added to a front end component which communicated with the server

Daniel

Comment: Are you also using ReactJS? Can you show me the frontend part?

Answer (score 0):

did some minor changes and it working fine.

```
import React from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

socket.emit('test', {
 message: 'oh hi'
})

export const FarmerPayment = () => {
 return <p> Sample </p>
}
```